# POE::Kernel->run() takes around 15 seconds to stop/

Tags: perl, httpresponse, poe

This is my code, have redacted the "use" statements. They all are working as desired.

```
my $json_data;

sub request {
    my ( $method, $container, $params, $content_type) = @_;

    #get the complete URL, works fine
    my $full_url = get_url( $method, $container, $params, $content_type);

    POE::Component::Client::HTTP->spawn(Alias => 'ua');

    # Start a session that will drive the resolver.
    # Callbacks are named functions in the "main" package.
    POE::Session->create(
    inline_states => {
        _start       => \&_start,
        got_response => \&got_response,
        }
    );

    POE::Kernel->run();
    return $json_data;
}

sub _start {
    my $kernel = $_[KERNEL];
    $kernel->post("ua" => "request", "got_response", $full_url);
}

sub got_response {
    my ($response_packet) = $_[ARG1];

    my $http_response = $response_packet->[0];
    my $response_string = $http_response->decoded_content();
    $json_data = decode_json( $response_string);
    print Dumper $json_data;
}
```

The Dumper in **got_response** prints the value instantly, but after that I have to wait at least 15 seconds for the return statement after **POE::Kernel->run** to execute. It returns the correct value but I can't wait that long.
If I add exit after the **sub get_reponse dumper** statement, then no value is returned.

Any help and suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`run()` will not return until every session has ended. This includes sessions that were created while run() was running.

Define the constant `POE::Kernel::TRACE_REFCNT` before using the first POE module, and you will receive a dump of which resources are in use throughout your program's lifetime.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

sub POE::Kernel::TRACE_REFCNT () { 1 }
use POE;

# ...

$poe_kernel->run();
exit 0;
```

Comment: Thanks it helped. I was having 3 sessions.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more detail on the specific problem listed.  The [POE::Component::Client::HTTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/POE::Component::Client::HTTP) module uses [POE::Component::Client::Keepalive](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/POE::Component::Client::Keepalive), which in turn uses [POE::Component::Resolver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/POE::Component::Resolver).  POE::Component::Resolver has a default timeout of 15 seconds.

The easiest way to immediately close down the resolver is to shutdown the HTTP session when you're finished with it:

```
$kernel->post("ua" => "shutdown");
```